# Quadratic bezier curve math

Tags: javascript, math

Can someone help me with this:
When I have a bezier curve like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FX0KJBP2EZ3S

```
P0(X) = 0 P0(Y) = 50
P1(X) = 100 P1(Y) = 25
P2(X) = 200 P2(Y) = 50
```

and make the bezier curve smaller like this:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FX0KL478CRY4

the P1 is higher due to the distance P0.X and P2.X. How can I keep the height of P1 so it is allways in the same height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shrink curve proportionally (to make the same form but smaller) you have to change **differences** of control points in the same ratio. So `Y1-Y0` should be changed similar to `(X2'-X0')/(X2-X0)` : `25 / (200/50) = 6.25`. In integers:

```
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(25, 44, 50, 50);
```

Comment: I knew it depended on the X difference, but I could not do the math. Thank you, that works great.

Comment: I have a problem when P0.Y and P2.Y are different. For example, Y0 = 20 and Y2 = 50. So the P1.X is not exactly in the middle. Should I calculate the angle between P0.Y and P2.Y and subtract it from P1.X?

Comment: No, you cannot make actions mixing Y and X. Just scale all differences relative to the first point: P1.X-P0.X, P2.X - P0.X, P1.Y-P0.Y, P2.Y-P0.Y in the same degree (for example, divide by 4)

Comment: I understand this not. When I have a degree of 4 and have this: (0, 20, 100, 10, 200, 50) should I make (10-20)/4 to get the X1?

Comment: If point P0 is stationary: (0, 20, 100/4, 20 + (10-20)/4, 200/4, 20 + (50-20)/4)

Comment: Something I do wrong or understand it not. In the first post I had this (0, 50, 100, 25, 200, 50). Based on the ratio 4 we change it to: (0, 50, 100, 44, 50, 50). So when I change the Y0 dynamic I become this: (0, 20, 25, 17.5, 50, 27.5) but this returns not the correct result. Y2 should be 50 (because I don't change it) and X1 should be something 30. But with this: (10-20)/4+20 I get 17.5 as result. I want keep the ratio of 4 but Y0 and Y2 is dynamic.

Comment: Could you show a sketch/picture - what do you really need?

Comment: The way you post work‘s fine when Y0 and Y2 has the same height. Please look here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXDIZMBCCYNA

But when I have different Y0 and Y2 the X1 is not in the middle
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXDJ733KQZM4

Comment: For the second case `ctx.moveTo(0, 150); ctx.quadraticCurveTo(50, 75, 100, 100);` gives curve shrinked in 2 times

Comment: Thanks but I want keep the the value for Y0 150, X2 200 and Y2 50. Now the value for Y1 is 44 but the X1 100 is not in the middle, how I can make the math for this? Please look here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXDJU8DTNY69 as you see the X1 is not in the middle it should be something like 50 instead 150 but how I can do the math without changing the other values?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the last curve. Why Y1 is 44? Why X1 is not in the middle?

Comment: I edit the comment above. I want a curve like a arc but with a ratio of 4 and with different Y0 and Y2 (this can be different and will be changed dynamic). But when the distance of Y0 and Y2 is large then the X1 is not in the middle and the arc looks not as it should.

Comment: OK, seems I am unable to understand. My answer adresses asked question and says that to make curve smaller (but preserving overall form), one have to change control points coordinates proportionally. Perhaps it is worth to make new question but make a picture to explain your need more clear.