# Bezier curve math

Tags: javascript, math

[3 weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329826/quadratic-bezier-curve-math) I asked a question on how to keep the ratio for the bezier curve when changing the X points. "MBo" helps me, but there was a problem and he recommend me to make a new  topic.

The problem is that P0.Y and P2.Y can be different and therefore the curve looks like a "brolly".

Now I have this and when changing P0.X and P2.X I want keep the ratio which work's fine:
[image: https://ibb.co/4WJfyjG]
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXDIZMBCCYNA

When changing P0.Y for example it looks like a "brolly" (the P1.X is not exactly in the middle):
[image: https://ibb.co/NKyXHyG]
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXDJ733KQZM4

**OK, I try to explain it more closely.**

I have four points (X1, Y1, X2, Y2) and want a bezier curve based on the points so:
P0.X is on X1, P1.X between X1 and X2, and P2.X on X2.
P0.Y is on Y1 and P2.Y on Y2.

When I now have this:

```
ctx.moveTo(0, 50);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(100, 25, 200, 50);
```

And change the position of x1 and x2 I keep the ratio from above:

```
ctx.moveTo(0, 50);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(25, 44, 50, 50);
```

Ok, so far this part work's fine. Now my problem is when I change the Y1 or Y2 it looks like "brolly" also the curve is not round like above because the P1.X is not exactly in the middle.

```
ctx.moveTo(0, 250);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(100, 25, 200, 50);
```

[image]

Where it should like this:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329826/quadratic-bezier-curve-math The question is how I can keep the ratio like in the first picture when changing the X and Y points so that it looks not a "borlly" like in the second picture.

Comment: That is so vague that it can mean anything... if you change control points you actively change the shape and size of the curve so what exactly you want? find interval in which the curve forms a specified aspect ratio?  or proportionally scale/position the curve to match some BBOX? or what? as you can see its still unclear... You should edit in the new info ...  into your question Also you should add the curve itself (contorl points and type of curve ...) MCVE would be even better as lot of us are lazy to code it from scratch Btw by clearly describing the problem some usually found the solution

Comment: Also how is this question different from the linked one? If they are the same do not post duplicate ones instead add new info into your original Question and comment others in there to notify them of new info ...

Comment: You have 4 questions with anwers but haven't marked none of them as solved.

Comment: BTW, question is not clear again. Please try to make better description.

Comment: @JCss well it still needs some tweaking ... like quadratic curve needs 3 points not 2 ... in text you are writing about 4 and in brakets you got 2, in code you got 2 and one in moveto so what to heck ?

Comment: I assume `moveTo` is first control point and `quadraticCurveTo` are the next two .. now you are changed the last 2 control points and wandering the shape and aspect ratio has changed? how you want preserve aspect ratio ... resp what values you want to compute ?  we do nto knwo why are you changing both x and y coordinates nor what is the background so we do not know what values we can change safely nor how ... the only thing I can recommend is to keep the changes between x and y proportional ...

Comment: Do you want to rotate curve? To rotate with some scaling? (when you shift y2, then distance p0-p2 is changing)

Comment: @MBo heh rotation did not occurred to me at all :)

Comment: @MBo Yes it is like rotation with scaling. I just want a curve between two points(x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it like this:

[image: quadratic bezier]

So you got some 3 points (`P0(x0,y0),P1(x1,y1),P2(x2,y2)`). Now what you want to do is **still unclear** but I assume you just want to resize the curve along `x` axis and maintain the shape in `y` axis too...

So you need to change all the stuff proprtionaly... so maintaining this:

```
(x1-x0) /  (x2-x0) = (x1'-x0') /  (x2'-x0')
(y1-y0) /  (y2-y0) = (y1'-y0') /  (y2'-y0')
(x1-x0) /  (x1'-x0') = c
(y1-y0) /  (y1'-y0') = c
(x2-x0) /  (x2'-x0') = c
(y2-y0) /  (y2'-y0') = c
(x2-x1) /  (x2'-x1') = c
(y2-y1) /  (y2'-y1') = c
```

where `x,y` are original points and `x',y'` are the changed ones

for your example:

```
P0=(  0,50)
P1=(100,25)
P2=(200,50)
x2'=50
```

you need to recompute the rest start with scale:

```
c = (x2-x0) / (x2'-x0') = (200-0)/(50-0) = 200/50 = 4
```

then just recompute what is missing:

```cpp
(x1-x0) / c = (x1'-x0') // x0=0, x0'=0 
x1 / c = x1'
x1' =  100/4 = 25

(y1'-y0') = (y1-y0) / c  // y0' = y0
y1' = (y1-y0) / c + y0
y1' = (25-50) / 4 + 50
y1' = 43.75

(y2'-y0') = (y2-y0) / c  // y0' = y0
y1' = (y2-y0) / c + y0
y1' = (50-50) / 4 + 50
y1' = 50
```

The same goes for changing `y` ... once you change any `y` you need to recompute the remaining `x,y` affected in the same manner...

Comment: Thank you Spektre. I will try that soon because I need time to understand it :)

Comment: @JCss the point is just to maintain the same ratio between control point so when you change any coordinate you must recompute others to match ... If you want to rotate instead of resize then you need to rotate all the points by the same angle around the same center instead

Answer (score 0):

When Bezier curve undergoes some affine transformation, the same transform is applied to their control points.

In your case transform is rotation and scaling around the first point (P0) of the curve.

Rotation angle is

```
 fi = arctan((P2'.Y - P2.Y) / (P2.X - P0.X))
```

Scaling coeficient

```
 Cf = Sqrt(1 + (P2'.Y - P2.Y)^2/(P2.X - P0.X)^2)
```

So new coordintes for control points are

```
xx = P1.X - P0.X
yy = P1.Y - P0.Y
nx = xx * Cos(fi) - yy * Sin(fi) 
ny = xx * Sin(fi) + yy * Cos(fi) 
P1'.X = P0.X + nx * Cf
P1'.Y = P0.Y + ny * Cf
```

Comment: Thank you MBo. I'll test it over the weekend and answer them.

Comment: Work's great this way. Thank you!